# Create an autocompleting UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITextField that displays a table view with all autocomplete options when the user types. This works great but I was wondering how I could change it so that when the user is typing, it shows the rest of the word in grey IN the text view, instead of displaying the results in a UITableView. So if the user types "y" then "es" would appear in the text view in gray. How would I do something like this.

Here is the code I am using to do it with a uitableview -

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    self.autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
    self.theLine2.hidden = NO;

    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring
                 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}


- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

    // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
    // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
    [self.autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString *curString in self.pastURLs) {
        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.location == 0) {
            [self.autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];
        }
    }
    [self.autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: And the new characters should be selected? Or you re-vandalise for each text change and update the text? Can you use an attributed string?

Comment: So it would be like the rest of the word is gray and if the user either taps it or clicks next it fills it in (like how xcode works in places)@Wain